# Rails - show last record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, structure

I am trying to show the last updated record of 'weight' from this DB:

[DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFlGx.png)

I am trying to call it using:

```
<%= @user.weights.last %>
```

I didn't get an error but I get this string printed:

```
<Weight:0x007f80814ab538>
```

Tried all sorts!

Comment: Why don't you put the result in the controller through using scope in the model?  Or simply do something like:  last_weight = Weight.last,  then last_weight.weight

Comment: the `last` method does not do anything with last updated. It orders by id desc and gets the first record.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a Weight object being returned. Try calling a field attribute on that:

```
@user.weights.last.weight
```

Comment: That doesn't output anything, unfortunately.

Comment: The suggested code looks right, could you try to add a `.inspect` or do a breakpoint and inspect the value, it could be a problem that your view is not outputting the value correctly

Answer (score 0):

get last updated user' weights

```
@last_weight  = @user.weights.order("updated_at DESC").first
```

the result is:

```
<Weight:0x007f80814ab538>
```

And you need to show the attibutes of Weight in your template

```
<%= @last_weight.attribute_1 %>
<%= @last_weight.attribute_2 %>
```